# Webrick and Firefox on Localhost - Repeated Request of Every JavaScript File Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

## The Problem:

With ***Firefox*** and ***Webrick***, every `JavaScript` `(.js)` `file type` is ***repeatedly requested***, which causes every *page load* to be too slow.

## With Internet Explorer:

With Internet Explorer the re-occurring request of every `JavaScript` `(.js)` `file type` does not happen on every *page load*.

The *processing message* of *every page load* looks similar to the following example:

```
Started GET "/home/css_middle_two" for *[localhost]*
Processing by HomeController#css_middle_two as HTML
  Rendered home/css_middle_two.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 62ms (Views: 62.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

## With Firefox:

With ***Firefox*** it does happen - together - with the re-occurring processing message `304 Not Modified`.

Having the `cache` and `cookies` cleared in ***Firefox***, will cause 
the ***first time*** request of every `JavaScript` `(.js)` `file type` to be successful - yet after that, the *re-occurring request* of every `JavaScript` `(.js)` `file type` on ***every page load*** will still happen.

Every *processing message* looks similar to this example:

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.effe
ct-drop.js?body=1" for *[localhost]*
Served asset /jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.effect-drop
.js - 304 Not Modified (15ms)
```

## The Question:

What is causing this - when even having the `cache` and `cookies` of ***Firefox*** cleared ?

---

The repeated request is done by the cache of Firefox. Though, what is causing the call for the repeated request? Which means, by which factor is the call for the repeated request caused?